# How do I stop Firefox from forcing https:// on local development server?

Tags: firefox, redirect, https

I am running a development environment on my Macintosh using AMPPS.

I have a folder with my project files. I have added this to my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

and I have set up the virtual domain accordingly.

When I attempt to connect to the site using Firefox:

```
http://www.example.com
```

it always redirects to:

```
https://www.example.com
```

and then complains about it.

The folder has nothing else in it but a dummy `index.html` file.

When I test the site in **lynx** or in **Safari** or **Chrome**, I get to my sample site. When I test in Firefox, that’s when I get the problem.

Firefox is my main browser, so it is possible that I have a caching problem, but I cannot see any method of clearing the cache that I haven’t tried already: trying to forget the page or clearing the cache.

I have tried all the suggestions mentioned here and elsewhere, but I am obviously missing something.

How do I stop Firefox from doing this?

Comment: Similar question [Firefox allow HTTP URLs (and not force HTTPS)](https://superuser.com/questions/1721511/firefox-allow-http-urls-and-not-force-https/1808600)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

- go to `about:config`
- search for `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` and set it to `false` (double click)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Even after the change, Firefox still redirects to https://. Firefox v. 86.0 (64-bit)
MaxOS Big Sur v. 11.2.2

Comment: Also does not work for me on ubuntu 20 firefox 87

Comment: Doesn't work for me too on Elementary OS and Firefox 105.0.3 :/